# Determine the Automorphism group of the unit bidisc.

Tags: several-complex-variables

I'm currently reading through *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* by R. Michael Range, and I'm stuck on Exercise E.2.4, which states

> Let $\Delta^2$ be the unit bidisc in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Show that every $f\in\text{Aut}(\Delta^2)$ is of the form $f=(f_1,f_2)$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ depend each on only one variable and $f_1,f_2\in\text{Aut}(\Delta)$. (Hint: By using an automorphism of the above simple type, reduce the general case to the case where $f(0)=0$.)

I'm essentially trying to recreate the proof (from Schwarz lemma) of this fact from one variable, but I'm running into trouble. I understand the hint, so I've been looking at $f\in\text{Aut}(\Delta^2)$, such that $f(0)=0$.

What I know so far is that, if $f=(f_1,f_2)$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_1}(0,0)\right|&\leq 1, & \left|\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z_2}(0,0)\right|&\leq 1,\\
\left|\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z_1}(0,0)\right|&\leq 1, & \left|\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z_2}(0,0)\right|&\leq 1, 
\end{align*}
by repeated use of the one variable Schwarz lemma. The same thing holds for the inverse $f^{-1}$, and I also know that it must be case that $f'(0)(f^{-1})'(0)=\text{Id}$, but I'm stuck at this point. If I could show that $f_1,f_2$ were dependent on only one of the variables, I'd probably be in business, but alas, I've not been able to do so.

I've looked up the proof in *Function Theory of Several Complex Variables* by Steven Krantz for the "$n$-disc," and it seems fairly nontrivial, so I suppose there is a more simplistic way for just two variables. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, I'm curious how Krantz proves it. Can you outline his proof?

Comment: @DanielFischer Absolutely! Thank you for taking the time to reply as well. Sorry for being so late to mark as answered, I had to find time to read it. I don't want you to think your work was in vein. I'll post post an outline of how Krantz proves it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how Krantz proves it, so maybe what I suggest is exactly the way Krantz uses. The argument works the same for arbitrary $n$, I don't see how special-casing $n = 2$ could lead to a simpler proof.

You are on the right track with using the Schwarz lemma, but you need to use it to get a little stronger result than you have. For a point $p\in \partial_0 \Delta^n$ consider $h \colon \Delta \to \Delta$ given by $h(z) = f_i(z\cdot p)$. The Schwarz lemma says $\lvert h'(0)\rvert \leqslant 1$, so

$$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0)\cdot p_k\Biggr\rvert \leqslant 1$$

for all $p$ in the distinguished boundary of $\Delta^n$. Thus it follows that

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \biggl\lvert \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0)\biggr\rvert \leqslant 1$$

for all $i$. The analogous estimate holds for the inverse $g$ of $f$, and since

$$1 = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0)\cdot \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial z_i}(0)$$

by the chain rule, we have the implications

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0) \neq 0 \implies \biggl\lvert \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial z_i}(0)\}\biggr\rvert = 1,$$

and the same with the roles of $f$ and $g$ interchanged. Hence, for all $i,k$, we have either $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0) = 0$ or $\bigl\lvert \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0)\bigr\rvert = 1$.

After a permutation and rotations of the components of $f$, we can thus assume $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k}(0) = \delta_{ik}$, or $J_f(0) = I$.

Then it remains to see that $f$ is the identity. The argument for that uses Montel's theorem and a theorem of Weierstrtaß. By Montel's theorem - the generalisation to dimensions greater than $1$ is straightforward - for a bounded domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, the family of holomorphic maps $F\colon U \to U$ is normal. By Weierstraß' theorem - again the generalisation to arbitrary (finite) dimensions is straightforward - the families of derivatives (of fixed [multi-]order) of a normal family is again normal.

It follows that if $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a bounded domain with $0\in U$, and $h\colon U \to U$ is holomorphic with $h(0) = 0$ and $J_h(0) = I$, then $h = \operatorname{id}_U$.

To see that, write

$$h(z) = z + H_k(z) + O(\lVert z\rVert^{k+1})$$

where $H_k$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k > 1$ (with values in $\mathbb{C}^n$). By induction, show that

$$h^m(z) = z + m\cdot H_k(z) + O(\lVert z\rVert^{k+1}),$$

where $h^m$ denotes the $m$-fold iterate of $h$, $h^{m+1} = h^m\circ h$. Use the normality of the family of derivatives of degree $k$ of the functions $h^m$ to deduce $H_k \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the Krantz proves it in *Function Theory of Several Complex Variables*.

**Preliminary Proposition**

He first proves a Proposition (11.1.2):

> Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be a bounded circular domain. Assume that $0\Omega$. Let $\phi\in\text{Aut}\Omega$ satisfy $\phi(0)=0$. Then $\phi$ is linear.

He proves this by introducing a function $\rho_{\theta}(z)=e^{i\theta}z$, $0\leq \theta <2\pi$, and then defining
$$
\psi:=\rho_{-\theta}\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\rho_{\theta}\circ\phi.
$$
He proceeds to show that $\psi'=\text{Id}$, and so your result (your result is actually the previous proposition) asserts that $\psi(z)\equiv z$. Since $\phi\circ\rho_{\theta}=\rho_{\theta}\circ\phi$ for all $\theta$, and the only monomials that commute with the $\rho_{\theta}$ are linear polynomials, $\phi$ is linear.

**Proof Outline of Main Theorem**

To prove the main theorem, he assumes $f(0)=0$, so that the previous proposition immediately applies to say that $f$ is linear. So $f(z)=(b_{ij})(z), 1\leq i,j\leq n$. He lets
$$
z^{ik}=\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\overline{\text{sgn }b_{i1}},\ldots ,\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\overline{\text{sgn }b_{in}}\right),
$$
where $\text{sgn}=z/|z|$. The $i^{\text{th}}$ component of $f(z^{ij})$ is $$\sum_{j=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\big|b_{ij}\big|.$$
This is less than one, so letting $k\to\infty$ shows $\sum_j|b_{ij}|\leq 1$. He then observes the behavior of $w^{jk}=(0,\ldots,0,(1-1/k),0,\ldots ,0)$, where only the $j^{\text{th}}$ entry is nonzero, as $k\to\infty$  (it is shown that $w^{jk}\to\partial \Delta^n$) to conclude each column has precisely one element of modulus 1. He then rules out a few cases to show that $f$ must be a rotation in each component.

Hopefully this is in enough detail. Thanks again.